# pandas dataframe index error: AssertionError: Lengths of index and values did not match

Tags: python, cloud, dataframe, pandas

I am trying to run some model simulations on PiCloud and deal with the results with Pandas.  (PiCloud is basically an interface to the Amazon cluster, through which I run things on an Ubuntu 11.04 virtual environment).

The problematic command seems to be:

```
fplf_df = pd.DataFrame(fpld, columns = var_name_list, index = sample_names_ordered)
```

fpld is a dict (61 keys that are strings, and values are one numpy array(length 1) and the rest floats), and var_name_list and sample_names_ordered are lists or arrays of strings.

When I run the script containing the command, all the PiCloud jobs terminate with this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/local/picloud/.employee/pimployee/job_util.py", line 119, in process_job
  result = func(*args, **kwargs)
 File "/home/itchy/ecopetrol/ec-working/pecube_scripts/run_eceS1_cloud.py", line 297, in  run_pecube_map
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 125, in __init__
sdict, columns, index = self._init_dict(data, index, columns, dtype)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 176, in _init_dict
v = Series(v, index=index)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 172, in __new__
subarr.index = index
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 193, in _set_index
raise AssertionError('Lengths of index and values did not match!')
AssertionError: Lengths of index and values did not match!
```

The bugger is that it works fine when I run it on my machine, and it works when I ssh into the virtual environment on Amazon's servers and make the DataFrame manually with IPython.  I have also tried to reproduce the error by giving index arguments that don't exist, or other arbitrary index arguments, and some are successful and others aren't, but none raise this particular error.  It seems to me (confirmed by manual tests) that it shouldn't matter exactly what the length of the index is because the values only compose one row, so when the index is added it just fills down, which is exactly what I want.

So what exactly causes this error?  I doubt the root of the problem lies with Pandas, but I think that if i have some idea what might be going wrong at the Pandas level, I can figure out what is going wrong with the communication from my machine to the virtual env (or whatever the real problem is).

For what it's worth:
My machine has pandas 0.9.1rc1 (latest bleeding-edge Ubuntu 12.04 update, maybe this morning) and the Amazon env has 0.9.0 (I think) from an egg in mid-October.  On Amazon, IPython and regular python calls from the terminal seem to be importing the same version of Pandas.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: It might be a bug. Have you tried 0.9.0 on your local machine? It'd be preferable to move further discussion from here to GitHub if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that [PiCloud's](http://www.picloud.com) default environment runs an older version of pandas (0.3.0) which causes incompatibilities.  The easiest solution is to use PiCloud's [Ubuntu Precise Environment](http://blog.picloud.com/2012/10/24/new-base-environment-ubuntu-precise/), which runs pandas 0.9.0.